# Illustrator Scripting how to get the angle of an object

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

How to get angle of GroupItem or Layer ?

I tried this, but it not works for me:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var sel = doc.selection[0];
if(sel.tags.length > 0 && sel.tags[0].name == "BBAccumRotation"){
    alert(sel.tags[0].value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working, but it's giving you Radians -- you'll have to convert to degrees:

```js
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var sel = doc.selection[0];

function rad2Deg(n) {
  return n * (180 / Math.PI);
}
if (sel.tags.length > 0 && sel.tags[0].name === "BBAccumRotation") {
  alert(rad2Deg(sel.tags[0].value));
}
```